# mongodb: compound multiKey indexes works, but is inherently slow?

Tags: mongodb, multi-index

[mondodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-type-multikey) says

> You cannot create a compound multikey index if more than one to-be-indexed field of a document is an array.

however on a [different place in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#multikey-embedded-documents%20it%20says) it says:

> The following operation creates a multikey index on the stock.size and stock.quantity fields:
>
> db.inventory.createIndex( { "stock.size": 1, "stock.quantity": 1 } )
>
> The compound multikey index can support queries with predicates that
>   include both indexed fields as well as predicates that include only
>   the index prefix

These two statements don't go together.

I followed the example given on the latter page. Here is a simplified version:

```
db.inventory.drop({})

db.createCollection("inventory")

db.inventory.insert(
{
  _id: 1,
  item: "abc",
  stock: [
    { size: "S", color: "red", quantity: 25 }
  ]
}
)

db.inventory.createIndex( { "stock.size": 1, "stock.quantity": 1 } )

db.inventory.find( { "stock.size": "M" } )
db.inventory.find( { "stock.size": "S", "stock.quantity": { $gt: 20 } } ).explain()
```

Point is, I can create the compound multi-index. 
However the query plan shows that it does not apply it fully:

[image: query plan]

It does an index scan with the compound index. However in the FETCH stage it still needs to filter for the field that is actually second part of the index. This means that it did actually not apply the second part of the index.

And this means, that such a query will be inherently slow, when there is a lot of data.

**Now my question:**

Is my finding correct? Is really the second doc (that contradicts the first) correct. 
Or am I overlooking something. Because ... when I am really right, we have a BIG issue here :-o :-D

Comment: In that index you created, the only field that is an array is `stock`, so it seems like it is technically correct.  The other parts about index coverage and sorting seems unclear at best.   It might be worth opening a ticket in their bug tracker to get someone to take a look at that

Comment: Try using the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#a-single-nested-document-meets-multiple-query-conditions-on-nested-fields) to query the array of embedded documents (his is for the query with multiple conditions).

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction. The document you provided in your example has a single array. The page you referenced has a relevant quote:

> You can create a compound index on { "a.x": 1, "a.z": 1 }. The restriction where at most one indexed field can be an array also applies.

In this case, the only array is `a`.

Regarding the index being used partially, this seems to be correct, but the index as you created it can be used for enforcing uniqueness using fields of documents in arrays in the top-level document:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.inventory.createIndex( { "stock.size": 1, "stock.quantity": 1 } ,{unique:true})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "commitQuorum" : "votingMembers",
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591841133, 7),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591841133, 7)
}
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.inventory.insert({stock:[{size:1,color:1}]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.inventory.insert({stock:[{size:1,color:1}]})
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 11000,
                "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.inventory index: stock.size_1_stock.quantity_1 dup key: { stock.size: 1.0, stock.quantity: null }"
        }
})
```